# Render a template within another

Tags: handlebars.js

I am very new to handlebars.js so please forgive me if this is basic.
I have a gulp task setup that is building everything up and creates a `template.js` file for me.

I have created 2 templates `main.hbs` & `child.hbs`

Within my `main.hbs` I have an UL setup e.g.

```
<ul class="events" id="event-list">
    {{#events}}
    <!--here just to test list is populating<li>{{Title}}</li>-->
          //tried no luck  {{> child}}
          //no luck{{child}}
          //no luck {{{child}}}

    {{/events}}
</ul>
```

my `child.hbs` looks like

```
<li class="wrapper job-detail" data-roleid="{{Id}}">
        ..
    <p class="mb5"><span class="semibold">{{Title}}</span> - {{Date}}</p>
    ..
</li>
```

How can I get my child template to render? I know both the templates work as I have been able to call them both and each of them works.

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
gulp.src('asserts/templates/**/*.hbs')
  .pipe(handlebars())
  .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
  .pipe(declare({
      namespace: 'se.templates',
      noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
  }))
  .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('asserts/js/'));
   });
```

Comment: Did you register the `child` partial?

Comment: I dont think I have, as I am not sure where I would do that.Do I do that within my gulp task? I have updated my question with the task

Comment: I'm not familiar with gulp but have look [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#partials) this may help

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770526/how-to-get-gulp-handlebars-to-recognize-partials.  That one went unanswered.